# Nuxt Proxy with Vercel Deployment

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I'm using a proxy in my nuxt local environment, which I was hoping to deploy to Vercel. API call works nicely on my localhost, but when deployed to Vercel, I get a 403 Forbidden error. API key is all fine.

I use:

```
'nuxt-proxy-request'
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
  proxy: {
    options: [
      {
        target: 'https://apiurl.ai/api/inference',
        pathFilter: ['/api**'],
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
```

When doing a POST request on Vercel I get the error:

> [403] - POST
> https://myapp.vercel.app/api?access_token=xxxxxx&model_id=RR6lMmw

Is there a config I'm missing on Vercel? The response to the call is just a HTML page stating to enable javascript?

Any help would be great.

Comment: I can call the vercel API url in Postman, which correctly returns the results. Which means a CORS error. Is this on the Vercel side?